# autodesk forge viewer set selection color to default

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

at object selection I'm using below code to change the selected object color ,

```
viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().impl.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(1, 0, 0));
```

It works fine , but how do I set the selection color to default ?

I tried both

```
  viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().clearSelection();
```

and

```
viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().clearThemingColors();
```

but these methods doesn't seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong ? or what is the best practice to change color and revert it back to default ?

viewer version : 6*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selection color is actually hardcoded and not saved in any configuration. You need to reset the color by specifying the original color, like this:

```
 .impl.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(0.4, 0.6, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to change the color of a selected element I would highly advice to use [setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive) instead. This will set a theming color to the defined dbids, this can easily be cleared at any point. You could hook this up to a select event to have automatic clearing and reassigning of colors. You could handle this after initialising the viewer.

In v7:

```js
viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
    viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().clearThemingColors();
    event.dbIdArray.forEach(id => 
    {
       viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().setThemingColor(id, new THREE.Vector4(1,0,0,1)
    })
}
)
```

However if you did want to have this approach you would have to find out what the default color is and use `setSelectionColor` with this color to overwrite it:
*Edit* Thanks to Cyrille we now know ! so adjusted the color accordingly

```
viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().impl.setSelectionColor(new THREE.Color(0.4, 0.6, 1));
```

no clear function is defined.

Comment: setThemingColor does not work for objects that already have a color in my case . Did you experiance such scenario ?

Comment: For me it has always worked as expected. You could also try to add a custom material with color to any object in the model

Comment: oh okey i will try again , I did that but didnt work may be i did it wrong..
thank you

Comment: Hello , will you be able to provide me a proper example of this ? i mean how to add a custom material with color . Thanks in advance